# Why RecyclerView are under BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, xml

This is My code for XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/menus" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp" />
```

Who can i put RecyclerView bellow BottomNavigationView?

Comment: Depends on your layout manager, which presently isn't included in the XML snippet.   Either way, though, it's as simple as switching the order it's declared in XML -- or changing elevations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this as your activity's layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:menu="@menu/menus" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="450dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Give me more information about that example, please.